# How to display 'print margin' guide behind text

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse 3.8, I enabled the print margin to help me limit my lines to less than 80 characters. But, because I work a lot with external code with much longer lines, I set the guide color to light grey to prevent interference with text.

My problem is that some letters get distorted under the guide. For example, `o` appears like `c`. Is it possible to change the order so that the is guide is displayed behind the text instead of over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that there is no solution.
[Bug 17805 – [painting] Print margin drawn on top of text](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17805)